# Return default or raise an exception?

Tags: java, refactoring

I am confused about what is considered a good practice - is this decision language dependent? Suppose I have the following Java code:

```
public class Stack {
    public Integer pop() {
      if (isEmpty()) return null; // or some exception maybe?
          // else get and return the top item in the stack.
      };
    }
}
```

The client of the `pop` method expects some `Integer` value, so what would be the best approach to let the client know that the stack is empty?

Comment: I think it really depends on what you want to achieve. In any situation ask yourself: Is it an expected behavior that my API returns a default value? Does a user of my API need to know that it was a default value? Most of the time data/memory access or manipulation should throw exceptions if something went wrong. But for concepts that you created, it is up to you.

Comment: A good example of that is mathematics. Some undefined behaviors are set by convention (e.g. 0 to the 0th power equals 1, or 0! equals 1) and some are undefined (e.g. division by 0 or the indeterminate forms for limits). The first category returns default values whilst the latter throws exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning `null` or a default value is *usually* a bad practice and an exception should be preferred. The reason is that **you should always strive to fail as fast as you can** when something goes wrong. If you return `null` instead, you will get errors happening in some other place in the code and users of your API will have trouble finding where the problem was. This is called [Fail Fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast).

An exception to this rule of thumb is when your API will make users rely on exceptions for flow control, so if your stack does not support `isEmpty()`, an exception is not a good idea here. If you have a stack that can allow only `peek()`, `pop()`, and `add()` - for some reason, `isEmpty()` is not allowed to be part of the API.

What will happen to the code of your users for both approaches?

**Option 1** - Using `null`:

```
Integer x = stack.pop();
if (x != null) { 
    //do something with x
}
```

**Option 2** - Using exceptions:

```
Integer x = null;
try { 
    x = stack.pop();
} catch (MyException e) { }
//do something with x
```

The second is actually using the exceptions mechanism for flow control - which is a big flaw in API design.

Comment: @CodeYogi added more explanation about it.

Comment: So, what you are basically saying is that `Exceptions` are good for internal use but not for API designed to be used by external clients, right?

Comment: Hi Amit, I got your first point and that last example got me totally confused. Can you help me to understand it?

Answer (score 2):

You could throw an [`IllegalStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html).

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time.

Calling `pop()` on an empty stack is a call at an  inappropriate time.

**The more modern approach** would be to return an [`Optional<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) which is the recommended way in Java 8 to avoud `null` returns.

```
public class Stack {
  public Optional<Integer> pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) return Option.ofNullable(null);
    return Optional.of(valueOnTheStack);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop--), attempting to pop an element from an empty stack *should* yield an exception.

Thus, I think that in your case, you should do the same (assuming you are implementing this in Java). Other languages might deal with this differently though.

Comment: You are pointing to the specific language implementation so, you mean it depends on a particular language?

Comment: @CodeYogi: I've tried to come up with a practical example for your problem, especially considering that your code is in Java. In C#, you might have a `bool TryGet(int index, out T value)` method, which will return `false` if the item is not there, instead of throwing an exception. (**Important** I do now know if this method actually exists in C#, but I think that it should convey the point).

Comment: Your reasoning is the [appeal to authority logical fallacy](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/appeal-to-authority) that fact that java does it is not a reason by itself why it should be done.

Comment: @amit: I did not say that an exception should be thrown because Java says so, I said (at least I think and tried to) that an exception should be thrown because in the same scenario, the Java framework throws an exception, thus the OP's code would behave in a manner that people familiar with the Java framework are accustomed to.

Comment: @npinti Java pre to java 8 (still do, but now deprecated) had their notorious Data,Calander API - would you recommend someone to use it because it's java's default? or would you recommend them to use Joda's time (or some other better designed library)?

Comment: @amit I think the question is: if you do use the Date, Calendar API, shouldn't your code be consistent with what you use?

Comment: @amit: If the OP was using some Framework other than the Java API, I would recommend they follow the design methodology of that framework.

Answer (score 0):

In case of building an API, it should be abstract, and use Exceptions since it'll be integrated in a Java envoirnment, then pop operation would be like the following.

```
public Integer pop () throws Exception
{
    if (stack.isEmpty())
        throw new java.util.EmptyStackException();

    return stack.pop();
}
```

---

If I'm building this as a Web Service, then I'd do it in the following way. Basically to make sure that the standardization of different types of internal exceptions are represent through the return object of using the stack.

StackService

```
@WebService
class MyStack
{
    StackProvider provider;
    Stack stack;

    public MyStack (StackProvider provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
        this.stack = provider.readStack();
    }

    public void sync ()
    {
        provider.syncStack(stack);
    }

    public Integer pop ()
    {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            return new StackElement(StackElement.STACK_EMPTY);

        return new StackElement(stack.pop());
    }

    public void push (Integer val)
    {
        stack.push(val);
    }
}
```

StackElement

```
class StackElement
{
    public static final char STACK_EMPTY = 0;
    public static final char ELEMENT_VALID = 1;

    public Integer value;
    public char flag;

    public StackElement (Integer val)
    {
        this.value = val;
        this.flag = StackElement.ELEMENT_VALID;
    }

    public StackElement (char flag)
    {
        this.value = null;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public boolean isValid ()
    {
        return (flag == 1);
    }
}
```

Test

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        StackProvider provider = new StackProvider("...");

        // init

        MyStackService service = new MyStackService(provide);
        MyStackServiceSoap soap = service.getMyStackServiceSoap();

        // call pop operation

        StackElement element = soap.pop();

        // checking the value

        if (element.isValid())
          System.out.println("Stack.Pop ~ " + element.value);
        else
        {
          if (element.flag == StackElement.STACK_EMPTY)
            System.out.println("Stack is Empty");
          else
            System.out.println("Unknown error");
        }

    }
}
```